# How to pass value from controller to ascx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building this widget in Sitefinity CMS.
This is my controller

```
namespace SitefinityWebApp.Api.Controllers
{
    public class ATMBranchLocatorController : ApiController
    {
        [DefaultValue("Enter Title")]
        [DisplayName("Branch & ATM")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue("Enter description")]
        [DisplayName("Accessing the ATM / Branch features easy")]
        public string Paragraph { get; set; } 
   

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new ucATMLocator();
            model.Title = this.Title;
            model.Paragraph = this.Paragraph;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to pass title and paragraph Dynamically, when they are entered on the backend, to my ascx file

```
<div class="atmsearch-form">
     <h4><%= Title %></h4>
     <p><%= Paragraph %></p>
</div>
```

I am getting a "The name 'View' does not exist in the current context" error
Do I have to pass a asp:TextBox in my ascx file? And how can I pass it from my api controller to my ascx file Dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you created an API controller, but you need a Controller.

Move your controller to the MVC / Controllers folder, change the namespace to SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Controllers and you should be good to go.

Also, make sure you have a folder ATMBranchLocator in the MVC / Views folder and an Index view inside of it.

Comment: Is there another way I can keep the API controller and use a dynamic way to insert values to Title and Paragraph

Comment: No, the API controller cannot return a View as is your case.